# SP2-0003 Ill for timestamp. Please help

Tags: oracle-11g

May I know what's the problem with this? I keep on getting this "SP2-0003 Ill formed" on the timestamp. How can I solve this?

```
ACCEPT v_cheindatetime timestamp FORMAT 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS'
  PROMPT 'Enter Checkin Date & Time : '
ACCEPT v_cheoutdatetime timestamp FORMAT 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS'
  PROMPT 'Enter Checkout Date & Time : '

--execute the INSERT statement
INSERT INTO booking VALUES
('&v_cheindatetime','&v_cheoutdatetime');
```

Comment: What values are you entering?

Answer (score 1):

`timestamp` is not a valid type when using `ACCEPT`. Use `date`.

[SQL*Plus® User's Guide and Reference - ACCEPT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm#SQPUG026)

```
SQL> !cat 1.sql
ACCEPT v_cheindatetime date FORMAT 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS' PROMPT 'Enter Checkin Date and Time : '
ACCEPT v_cheoutdatetime date FORMAT 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS' PROMPT 'Enter Checkout Date and Time : '

--execute the INSERT statement
INSERT INTO booking VALUES
('&v_cheindatetime','&v_cheoutdatetime');

SQL> @1
Enter Checkin Date and Time : 06-AUG-16 12:00:00
Enter Checkout Date and Time : 07-AUG-16 12:00:00
old   2: ('&v_cheindatetime','&v_cheoutdatetime')
new   2: ('06-AUG-16 12:00:00','07-AUG-16 12:00:00')

1 row created.
```